# Add file name to first column at start of .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to add a new "filename" column at the start of a .csv file then add the name of the file to each line

Example input.csv

```
Date,Day,Server
2018-5-20,Su,ASA
2018-5-21,Su,ASA
```

Example Output

```
Filename,Date,Day,Server
input,2018-5-20,Su,ASA
input,2018-5-21,Su,ASA
```

It look's easy to add the filename to the end of the .csv using the csv module, but adding a new column at the start is looking more tricky.

Any help is appreciated

So far i have the below from searching silmilar questions online

```
with open(r'C:\Python\sys_status\output.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_output:
 csv_output = csv.writer(file_output)
 for fname in glob.glob(r'C:\Python\sys_status\input.csv'):
    with open(fname, newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        for row in csv_input:
            row.insert(0, fname)
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Using the above i'm unable to set a header name, instead it adds the whole path to the file name to the first column

```
C:\Python\input.csv,Date,Day,Server
C:\Python\input.csv,2018-5 -20,Su,ASA
C:\Python\input.csv,2018-5 -21,Su,ASA
```

Comment: Post the code you already have. Nobody can tell you how to change it to do what you want, if we don't know what you have now.

Comment: Done, apologies.

Comment: a minimum input.csv file would be welcome too. your indentation is broken (first with)

Comment: Fixed, added input.csv at the top

Comment: sorry i misread the glob for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `row` contains the header of CSV file. While writing a new csv file the first `writerow` should be used to write the header.

```
import csv, glob, os

with open(r'C:\Python\sys_status\output.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_output:
 csv_output = csv.writer(file_output)
 for fname in glob.glob(r'C:\Python\sys_status\input.csv'):
    with open(fname, newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

        # Header processing
        header = csv_input.__next__()
        header.insert(0, "filename")

        csv_output.writerow(header)
        for row in csv_input:
            print(row)
            row.insert(0, fname)
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

**Note** I suggest using `csv.DictWriter` and `csv.DictReader` which can be used to specify the field names to write/read and has a `writeheader` function. This doesn't give any significant advantage but make our code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
import os.path
import csv
import glob
with open(r'C:\Python\sys_status\output.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(file_output)
    for fname in glob.glob(r'C:\Python\sys_status\input.csv'):
        with open(fname, newline='') as f_input:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
            fname = os.path.split(fname).pop()
            for i, row in enumerate(csv_input):
                if i == 0:
                    row.insert(0, 'Filename')
                else:
                    row.insert(0, fname)
                csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Please use `os.path.split` instead of `fname.split('\\').pop()`